# Identify whether each member of a group has previously been in another group with any member of the current group

Tags: r, function, dplyr

My data has rows representing individual members who have belonged to different groups, with individual ID's ("ID") and group ID's ("GROUP_NUM").

I'm trying to write code which, for each group, loops through each individual ID, and checks if any of list(groups this ID has previously been in) occurs in list(groups all other IDs in the group have previously been in), and if so to add 1 for that ID to a new column called "HISTORY".

Example dataframe:

| ID | GROUP_NUM |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 1 |
| def | 1 |
| ghi | 1 |
| jkl | 1 |
| abc | 2 |
| mno | 2 |
| pqr | 2 |
| stv | 2 |
| abc | 3 |
| stv | 3 |
| wxy | 3 |
| zzz | 3 |
| abc | 4 |
| def | 4 |
| pqr | 4 |
| bbb | 4 |

Desired result:

| ID | GROUP_NUM | HISTORY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1 | 0 |
| def | 1 | 0 |
| ghi | 1 | 0 |
| jkl | 1 | 0 |
| abc | 2 | 0 |
| mno | 2 | 0 |
| pqr | 2 | 0 |
| stv | 2 | 0 |
| abc | 3 | 1 |
| stv | 3 | 1 |
| wxy | 3 | 0 |
| zzz | 3 | 0 |
| abc | 4 | 1 |
| def | 4 | 1 |
| pqr | 4 | 1 |
| bbb | 4 | 0 |

I've been able to identify individual examples when HISTORY should = 1, but would like to do this for the whole dataframe. The code seems like it would be quite complex to me and I can't get my head round it.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

Based on the OP's modified logic and expected output

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(indx = n_distinct(GROUP_NUM)) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(indx = indx * (duplicated(ID))) %>%
  group_by(GROUP_NUM) %>%
  mutate(HISTORY = +((indx > 0) & (sum(indx > 0) > 1)), indx = NULL) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 16 × 3
   ID    GROUP_NUM HISTORY
   <chr>     <int>   <int>
 1 abc           1       0
 2 def           1       0
 3 ghi           1       0
 4 jkl           1       0
 5 abc           2       0
 6 mno           2       0
 7 pqr           2       0
 8 stv           2       0
 9 abc           3       1
10 stv           3       1
11 wxy           3       0
12 zzz           3       0
13 abc           4       1
14 def           4       1
15 pqr           4       1
16 bbb           4       0
```

Comment: What does the `+` do here? turn the boolean into an integer?

Comment: @JuanC yes, coercion.  Otherwise you need `as.integer`

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion @akrun. But this returns 1 for any repeat appearance of the same ID. I only want a 1 if the ID is in a group with another ID and they have previously been in a group together.

Comment: @iwuzborn your input and output values were different when I tested it.  So was not sure

Comment: @akrun sorry I noticed a mistake and had to edit it. Is there a way to use duplicated for all combinations of ID's in a current group?

Comment: @iwuzborn I didn't fully understand your logic.  Perhaps the update helps you

Comment: @akrun that's awesome, thanks! I now also have a date variable, so how can I adjust this to only pick up shared group membership from *past* groups? The group numbers are not necessarily sequential...

Comment: @iwuzborn can you post as a new question. thanks

Comment: @akrun I've posted a new question here if you have any ideas I'd be really grateful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75792827/r-code-to-identify-whether-individuals-in-groups-have-previously-been-in-groups