# Identifying previously shared group membership between group members

Tags: r

My data has rows representing individuals who have belonged to different groups, with individual ID's ("ID") and group ID's ("GROUP_NUM"), and the date which groups were formed ("Date").

I'm trying to write R code to create a new column ("HistoryCount") displaying the number of times each member has been in an earlier group with any current group member.

Example dataframe:

| ID | GROUP_NUM | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1 | 2022-01-15 |
| def | 1 | 2022-01-15 |
| ghi | 1 | 2022-01-15 |
| jkl | 1 | 2022-01-15 |
| abc | 2 | 2022-02-19 |
| mno | 2 | 2022-02-19 |
| pqr | 2 | 2022-02-19 |
| stv | 2 | 2022-02-19 |
| abc | 3 | 2022-05-11 |
| stv | 3 | 2022-05-11 |
| wxy | 3 | 2022-05-11 |
| zzz | 3 | 2022-05-11 |
| abc | 4 | 2022-10-06 |
| def | 4 | 2022-10-06 |
| pqr | 4 | 2022-10-06 |
| bbb | 4 | 2022-10-06 |
| abc | 5 | 2021-04-14 |
| stv | 5 | 2021-04-14 |
| pqr | 5 | 2021-04-14 |
| bbb | 5 | 2021-04-14 |

Desired result:

| ID | GROUP_NUM | Date | HistoryCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1 | 2022-01-15 | 0 |
| def | 1 | 2022-01-15 | 0 |
| ghi | 1 | 2022-01-15 | 0 |
| jkl | 1 | 2022-01-15 | 0 |
| abc | 2 | 2022-02-19 | 1 |
| mno | 2 | 2022-02-19 | 0 |
| pqr | 2 | 2022-02-19 | 1 |
| stv | 2 | 2022-02-19 | 1 |
| abc | 3 | 2022-05-11 | 2 |
| stv | 3 | 2022-05-11 | 2 |
| wxy | 3 | 2022-05-11 | 0 |
| zzz | 3 | 2022-05-11 | 0 |
| abc | 4 | 2022-10-06 | 4 |
| def | 4 | 2022-10-06 | 1 |
| ddd | 4 | 2022-10-06 | 0 |
| stv | 4 | 2022-10-06 | 3 |
| abc | 5 | 2021-04-14 | 0 |
| stv | 5 | 2021-04-14 | 0 |
| pqr | 5 | 2021-04-14 | 0 |
| ccc | 5 | 2021-04-14 | 0 |

A previous solution from @akrun successfully identifies groups that include any members who have previously been in a group together: [Identify whether each member of a group has previously been in another group with any member of the current group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74522806/identify-whether-each-member-of-a-group-has-previously-been-in-another-group-wit)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(indx = n_distinct(GROUP_NUM)) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(indx = indx * (duplicated(ID))) %>%
  group_by(GROUP_NUM) %>%
  mutate(HISTORY = +((indx > 0) & (sum(indx > 0) > 1)), indx = NULL) %>%
  ungroup
```

I want to extend this by providing individual counts of previously shared membership, and making sure the counts are in temporal order.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a custom function and apply it rowwise. Note that your desired output is slightly different, but I guess that this are typos. The first approach below considers membership to a group id with a lower number in `GROUP_NUM` no matter the data. The second approach further below considers the `Date` of previous groups and doesn't care about the number of `GROUP_NUM`.

First approach based on number of `GROUP_NUM`:

```r
get_history_count <- function(thisid, group_nr) {
  
  if (group_nr == 1) {
    return(0)
  }
  
  filter_dat <- filter(dat, GROUP_NUM < group_nr) %>%
    group_by(GROUP_NUM) %>% 
    filter(any(thisid %in% ID))
  
  n_distinct(filter_dat$GROUP_NUM)
}

dat %>%
  rowwise(GROUP_NUM) %>% 
  mutate(HistoryCount = get_history_count(ID, cur_group()$GROUP_NUM))
#> # A tibble: 20 x 4
#> # Rowwise:  GROUP_NUM
#>    ID    GROUP_NUM Date       HistoryCount
#>    <chr>     <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>
#>  1 abc           1 2022-01-15            0
#>  2 def           1 2022-01-15            0
#>  3 ghi           1 2022-01-15            0
#>  4 jkl           1 2022-01-15            0
#>  5 abc           2 2022-02-19            1
#>  6 mno           2 2022-02-19            0
#>  7 pqr           2 2022-02-19            0
#>  8 stv           2 2022-02-19            0
#>  9 abc           3 2022-05-11            2
#> 10 stv           3 2022-05-11            1
#> 11 wxy           3 2022-05-11            0
#> 12 zzz           3 2022-05-11            0
#> 13 abc           4 2022-10-06            3
#> 14 def           4 2022-10-06            1
#> 15 pqr           4 2022-10-06            1
#> 16 bbb           4 2022-10-06            0
#> 17 abc           4 2021-04-14            3
#> 18 stv           4 2021-04-14            2
#> 19 pqr           4 2021-04-14            1
#> 20 bbb           4 2021-04-14            0
```

Second approach based on `Date`:

```r
library(dplyr)

get_history_count <- function(thisid, thisdate) {
  
  filter_dat <- filter(dat,
                       Date < thisdate,
                       ) %>%
    group_by(GROUP_NUM) %>% 
    filter(any(thisid %in% ID))
  
  n_distinct(filter_dat$GROUP_NUM)
}


dat %>%
  rowwise(GROUP_NUM) %>% 
  mutate(HistoryCount = get_history_count(ID, Date))

#> # A tibble: 20 x 4
#> # Rowwise:  GROUP_NUM
#>    ID    GROUP_NUM Date       HistoryCount
#>    <chr>     <dbl> <chr>             <int>
#>  1 abc           1 2022-01-15            1
#>  2 def           1 2022-01-15            0
#>  3 ghi           1 2022-01-15            0
#>  4 jkl           1 2022-01-15            0
#>  5 abc           2 2022-02-19            2
#>  6 mno           2 2022-02-19            0
#>  7 pqr           2 2022-02-19            1
#>  8 stv           2 2022-02-19            1
#>  9 abc           3 2022-05-11            3
#> 10 stv           3 2022-05-11            2
#> 11 wxy           3 2022-05-11            0
#> 12 zzz           3 2022-05-11            0
#> 13 abc           4 2022-10-06            4
#> 14 def           4 2022-10-06            1
#> 15 pqr           4 2022-10-06            2
#> 16 bbb           4 2022-10-06            1
#> 17 abc           4 2021-04-14            0
#> 18 stv           4 2021-04-14            0
#> 19 pqr           4 2021-04-14            0
#> 20 bbb           4 2021-04-14            0
```

Data from OP:

```r
dat <- tribble(~ID, ~GROUP_NUM, ~Date,
  
  "abc", 1,"2022-01-15", 
  "def", 1,"2022-01-15", 
  "ghi", 1,"2022-01-15", 
  "jkl", 1,"2022-01-15", 
  "abc", 2,"2022-02-19", 
  "mno", 2,"2022-02-19", 
  "pqr", 2,"2022-02-19", 
  "stv", 2,"2022-02-19", 
  "abc", 3,"2022-05-11", 
  "stv", 3,"2022-05-11", 
  "wxy", 3,"2022-05-11", 
  "zzz", 3,"2022-05-11", 
  "abc", 4,"2022-10-06", 
  "def", 4,"2022-10-06", 
  "pqr", 4,"2022-10-06", 
  "bbb", 4,"2022-10-06", 
  "abc", 4,"2021-04-14", 
  "stv", 4,"2021-04-14", 
  "pqr", 4,"2021-04-14", 
  "bbb", 4,"2021-04-14")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @TimTeaFan, you're right there was a typo, now fixed. GROUP_NUM is the group ID, and they're not necessarily in date order. Does that change your answer?

Comment: @iwuzborn: Please define "previously shared membership". Is it the number of the group (ex. now group 2 previously group 1) or is it a group (no matter the number) that existed on a date before the date of the current group?

Comment: it's the latter

Comment: @iwuzborn: My answer shows both approaches. I hope its what your expected output looks like.