# R code to identify whether individuals in groups have previously been in groups together

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset of individuals who belong to different groups over time, sometimes with the same group members, sometimes with new members.

I'm trying to create a variable which displays a count of the number of times each individual in a group has been in an earlier group with any of the current group members, using the Date information to make sure the count is in chronological order (i.e. not counting shared membership from groups in the future).

Example data:

```
SampleData <- tribble(~ID, ~GROUP_NUM, ~Date,
               "abc", 22,"2022-01-15", 
               "def", 22,"2022-01-15", 
               "ghi", 22,"2022-01-15", 
               "jkl", 22,"2022-01-15", 
               "abc", 14,"2022-02-19", 
               "mno", 14,"2022-02-19", 
               "pqr", 14,"2022-02-19", 
               "stv", 14,"2022-02-19", 
               "abc", 18,"2022-05-11", 
               "stv", 18,"2022-05-11", 
               "wxy", 18,"2022-05-11", 
               "zzz", 18,"2022-05-11", 
               "abc", 35,"2022-10-06", 
               "def", 35,"2022-10-06", 
               "pqr", 35,"2022-10-06", 
               "bbb", 35,"2022-10-06", 
               "abc", 44,"2021-04-14", 
               "stv", 44,"2021-04-14", 
               "pqr", 44,"2021-04-14", 
               "bbb", 44,"2021-04-14")
```

Here's my desired output:

```
AimedData <- tribble(~ID, ~GROUP_NUM, ~Date, ~NPrevKnown,
                      "abc", 22,"2022-01-15", 0,
                      "def", 22,"2022-01-15", 0,
                      "ghi", 22,"2022-01-15", 0,
                      "jkl", 22,"2022-01-15", 0,
                      "abc", 14,"2022-02-19", 2,
                      "mno", 14,"2022-02-19", 0,
                      "pqr", 14,"2022-02-19", 2,
                      "stv", 14,"2022-02-19", 2,
                      "abc", 18,"2022-05-11", 2,
                      "stv", 18,"2022-05-11", 2,
                      "wxy", 18,"2022-05-11", 0,
                      "zzz", 18,"2022-05-11", 0,
                      "abc", 35,"2022-10-06", 4,
                      "def", 35,"2022-10-06", 1,
                      "pqr", 35,"2022-10-06", 3,
                      "bbb", 35,"2022-10-06", 2,
                      "abc", 44,"2021-04-14", 0,
                      "stv", 44,"2021-04-14", 0,
                      "pqr", 44,"2021-04-14", 0,
                      "bbb", 44,"2021-04-14", 0)
```

Comment: why is abc (group 22) 0? shouldn't it be 1?

Comment: It's 0 because none of the current group members were in a previous group with abc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most efficient but this might work!

```
SampleData <- dplyr::tribble(~ID, ~GROUP_NUM, ~Date,
                             "abc", 22,"2022-01-15", 
                             "def", 22,"2022-01-15", 
                             "ghi", 22,"2022-01-15", 
                             "jkl", 22,"2022-01-15", 
                             "abc", 14,"2022-02-19", 
                             "mno", 14,"2022-02-19", 
                             "pqr", 14,"2022-02-19", 
                             "stv", 14,"2022-02-19", 
                             "abc", 18,"2022-05-11", 
                             "stv", 18,"2022-05-11", 
                             "wxy", 18,"2022-05-11", 
                             "zzz", 18,"2022-05-11", 
                             "abc", 35,"2022-10-06", 
                             "def", 35,"2022-10-06", 
                             "pqr", 35,"2022-10-06", 
                             "bbb", 35,"2022-10-06", 
                             "abc", 44,"2021-04-14", 
                             "stv", 44,"2021-04-14", 
                             "pqr", 44,"2021-04-14", 
                             "bbb", 44,"2021-04-14"
)
SampleData$Date <-as.Date(SampleData$Date)

AimedData <- SampleData

AimedData$NPrevKnown <- sapply(1:nrow(SampleData),function(ROW){
  individual<-AimedData$ID[ROW]
  others <- unique(AimedData$ID[which(
    AimedData$GROUP_NUM==AimedData$GROUP_NUM[ROW]&
      AimedData$Date==AimedData$Date[ROW]&
      AimedData$ID!=AimedData$ID[ROW]
  )])
  if(length(others)>0){
    old_groups <- AimedData[which(
      AimedData$Date<AimedData$Date[ROW]& # added a less than here
        AimedData$ID==AimedData$ID[ROW]
    ),]
    old_pals<-NULL
    if(length(old_groups)>0){
      for (i in 1:nrow(old_groups)){
        old_pals<-append(
          old_pals,
          (AimedData$ID[which(
            AimedData$GROUP_NUM==old_groups$GROUP_NUM[i]&
              AimedData$Date==old_groups$Date[i]&
              AimedData$ID!=AimedData$ID[ROW])])
        )
      }
    }
  }
  length(which(old_pals %in% others))
})

AimedData$WhoPrevKnown <- sapply(1:nrow(SampleData),function(ROW){
  individual<-AimedData$ID[ROW]
  others <- unique(AimedData$ID[which(
    AimedData$GROUP_NUM==AimedData$GROUP_NUM[ROW]&
      AimedData$Date==AimedData$Date[ROW]&
      AimedData$ID!=AimedData$ID[ROW]
  )])
  if(length(others)>0){
    old_groups <- AimedData[which(
      AimedData$Date<AimedData$Date[ROW]& # added a less than here
        AimedData$ID==AimedData$ID[ROW]
    ),]
    old_pals<-NULL
    if(length(old_groups)>0){
      for (i in 1:nrow(old_groups)){
        old_pals<-append(
          old_pals,
          (AimedData$ID[which(
            AimedData$GROUP_NUM==old_groups$GROUP_NUM[i]&
              AimedData$Date==old_groups$Date[i]&
              AimedData$ID!=AimedData$ID[ROW])])
        )
      }
    }
  }
  paste0(old_pals,collapse = " | ")
})
```

Comment: Hi @Brandon, thanks this gets close! But I think it's only counting once per unique individual in old_pals, whereas I'm trying to count every time they've been together... e.g. shouldn't row 13 of AimedData show 4 for NPrevKnown? (abc has been with def once before, bbb once before, and pqr *twice* before)

Comment: OK I made the edit to account for that. How does it look?